# Validating price in java regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to validate a price range format. Following is the sequence of string:

```
"MSRP $250.00 - Event Price $129.00"
```

I tried like this:

```
String t=price1.replace("$","T");
t= t.replace(" ", "");
MSRPT([0-9]+).([0-9]+)-EventPriceT([0-9]+).([0-9]+)
```

But it is not being matched.

Thanks

Comment: According to you, is the string `"MSRP $250.00 - Event Price $129.00"` valid or invalid?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
MSRP\s\$([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+).*?\$([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)
```

Note that you need to escape `$` and `.` - dot is "any" character

but I would write:

```
MSRP\s+\$([\d\.]+).*?Event\sPrice\s+\$([\d\.]+)
```

And you will have in $1 and in $2 Strings of price value

Comment: Maybe this is over-specifying, but I'd write `^MSRP\s+\$([\d]+\.[0-9]{2}).*?Event\sPrice\s+\$([\d]+\.[0-9]{2})$`

Comment: Then you should add `,` in your regexp.